# Formating date in desired format as Date not as string

Tags: java, date

If i convert the string to date using simple date format..

```
SimpleDateFormat parser=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

System.out.println(parser.parse("2014-11-24"));
```

It return the value as Mon Nov 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014

I want it should be in format "yyyy-MM-dd" . If i use SimpleDateFormat format() method. It returns the value as string but i want the value should be in Date. not as a string. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

### `Date` != `String`

Your call to `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` returns a `Date` object, then you call `System.out.println()` which defaults to using the `toString()` of `Object`. The `Date` objects `.toString()` gets a `String` representation using its default format.

Why do you expect something different than what the JavaDoc clearly explains? `Date.toString()` is well documented.

If you want to print it out back in the format it came from that is what the `SimpleDateFormat.format()` method is for. But that would give you the value that you already parsed, so what you are trying to do demonstrates a fundamental lack of comprehension of Java and how to read `JavaDoc` and other basic fundamental skills required to program in the Java language.

If you took the time it took you to post this question to read the JavaDoc on the objects and methods on those objects this is explained in great detail!